# Volume and Triple Integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

When finding the volume of a solid using triple integrals, is the "integral" always $\int \int \int $ $dV$, regardless of what the "z function" is?

For instance, for the problem: Find the volume of the solid that lies within the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$, above the xy-plane, and below the cone $z$ = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Is the integral just $\int \int \int $ $dV$ with the correct bounds of integration, regardless of $z$ = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$? Thanks.

Comment: $\iiint \; \mathrm{d}V$ just symbolically means 3-dimensional integral over some volume-element $\text{d}V$. You must first determine over what volume-element you're integrating. (your case: some sphere with the lower half cut off and a cone cut out, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5zZr.png)

Comment: You can use `\iiint` to get a proper triple integral (as in the above comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have triple integral of type $\iiint F DV$ and region in some volume V. This means you are adding value of F over all points over V. But if F is 1, this means you're finding volume of V

Comment: You can check video 8 and 9 if this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6-FmPMbQE4